# Chart JS get instance after init chart

Tags: javascript, meteor, charts

I'm using chart cs in my meteor js app.

In my first method i create a new Chart.
In my second method i want to update this chart.

The problem is that i can't handle the instance of the chart to the second method.
Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Template.first.onRendered(function () {
  new Chart($('#myChart'), {...});
});

Template.second.events({
  'click .teach'() {
    var myChart = Chart.getInstance($('#myChart'));
    ...
});
```

Or have i to create a global variable to edit the chart in different controllers?

Answer (score -1):

Just re-instantiate the chart with the updated values

```
 new Chart($('#myChart'), {...});
```

this will redraw the chart and update the values;